# how to oracle patch in docker

Tags: database, oracle, docker, patch

i`m beginner docker user.

My development environment operates oracle EE 19.3 version in Docker CE 19.03.5. (RHEL7.7)

I would like to apply Oracle Patch (PSR,PSU,CPU,interim, etc.) to oracle engines that are being operated on existing docker containers and then export them. However, it is frustrating because no method can be found even when I try Google.

I want to patch Oracle 19c EE, which is on the docker, and then make it a new image. 
How do I apply patches after downloading the patch file from Oracle?

Please Let me know.

Comment: Oracle doesn't provide patches for XE to begin with.

Comment: really? Then, do you offer it to oracle EE? Is there a way?

Comment: I don't offer anything. But yes, you can get patches from Oracle for the EE version if you have a support contract

Comment: To get Oracle patches you must have an Oracle Support contract. So if you have access to get patches you should have access to MyOracleSupport. Can't they help?

Comment: I suggest you read [this github article by Oracle's Gerald Venzl on patching Docker images](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/samples/applypatch)

Answer (score 0):

When you download the patch zip file there is a readme file in it. It will tell you which commands you need to execute to apply the patch.